# converting date format

Tags: java, sql

I got date as `'14-Dec-2010'` i want to get the month in number format for the given date.
that is., i want to convert the date to `'14-12-2010'`.

Answer (score 5):

```
DateFormat inFm = new SimpleDateFormat("d-MMM-y");
DateFormat outFm = new SimpleDateFormat("d-M-yyyy");
Date date = inFm.parse("14-Dec-2010");
String output = outFm.format(date);
```

Generally, you should use a datetime type like `Date` internally, then transform to `String` at output time.

Comment: it will print 14-11-2010 I think

Comment: @org, no, it won't; try it.  `SimpleDateFormat` knows to use 1-based indices.   You're probably thinking of `Calendar`, which does use a 0-based month index.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
Date date= format.parse("14-Dec-2010");
```

This is how you will get Date Object now you can print it in any format.
**Note**: month starts from 0 , so for `Dec` it would be `11`

- [Here is working IDE One demo](http://ideone.com/DkTg0)
- [Document](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: It doesn't work and gives exception : java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "14-Dec-2010

Comment: I don't do anything different just copy and paste :) and it doesn't work . and your code also doesn't work for me. I don't know the reason it just throws an exception java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "14-Dec-2010". (OpenJDK java 1.6)

Comment: @hital which jdk you are using ?

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateFormatter {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date date = new Date("14-Dec-2010"); //deprecated. change it to your needs
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        System.out.println(df.format(date));

    }

}
```

Comment: That constructor is deprecated.  It's better to be explicit about what format you're expecting.

Answer (score 1):

I think this SQL convert should work

SELECT CONVERT(datetime,'14-Dec-2010',105)

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using the troublesome old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java. They are poorly designed and confusing.

## java.time

The old classes are supplanted by the java.time framework.

For a date-only value without time of day and without time zone use `LocalDate` class.

Parse the String input using `DateTimeFormatter`.

```
String input = "14-Dec-2010";

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MMM-yyyy" );
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( input , formatter );
```

To generate a String in another format, define another formatter.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-yyyy" );
String output = localDate.format( formatter2 );
```

Better yet, let `DateTimeFormatter` automatically localize.

```
Locale l = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ;  // Or Locale.US, Locale.ITALY, etc.
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.SHORT ).withLocale( l );
String output = localDate.format( f );  // Generates String in a localized format.
```

## SQL

For SQL just pass objects, do not use strings. Pass `LocalDate` via `setObject` on a `PreparedStatement` if your JDBC driver complies with the JDBC 4.2 spec.

```
myPrepStmt.setObject( localDate );
```

If not, fall back to the old `java.sql.Date` class by using new conversion methods added to the old classes.

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = java.sql.Date.from( localDate );
myPrepStmt.setDate( sqlDate );
```